# looping in php codeigniter views

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, foreach

I am getting an array like this:-

```
$query['data'] = $this->flights->checkflight($form_data);  //getting data
$this->load->view("payment",$query);   //sending to view
```

I am looping through data like this in the view. And i get errors like illegal string offset 'from','to' etc.

```
<tbody>
<?php
foreach($data as $flight):
?>
  <tr class="danger">
   <td> <?= $flight['from'] ?> </td>
   <td> <?= $flight['to'] ?> </td>
    <td><?=  $flight['date'] ?> </td>
     <td> <?=  $flight['time'] ?> </td>
     <td> <?=  $flight['seatsF'] ?> &nbsp; <?=  $flight['seatsB'] ?> &nbsp; <?=  $flight['seatsE'] ?>  </td>
     <td> <?=  $flight['priceF'] ?> &nbsp; <?=  $flight['priceB'] ?> &nbsp; <?=  $flight['priceE'] ?>  </td>
  </tr>      
  <?php
  endforeach;
  ?>
</tbody>
```

But in my view if I do:-

```
print_r($data);
```

I get something like this:-

```
Array ( [id] => 12348 [from] => asd [to] => as [date] => 2017-01-01 [time] => 01:00:00 [seatsF] => 0 [seatsB] => 1 [seatsE] => 1 [priceF] => 1000 [priceB] => 1000 [priceE] => 1000 [approved] => 0 [payment] => 1000 )
```

Please tell me how to correctly loop through $data, I have seen answers of "illegal offset" and applied those but thy didn't work out.

Comment: Ok so what do you get when you do a print_r($flight); inside your loop on your view?

Comment: I get the array which I wanted if I do print_r($flight); but I want seperate values as key-value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one row of data getting fetched from the database.
it's like [id, from, to, date, time ..] etc
now if you use "foreach" on this array then you will get each individual columns. like "id", "from" , "to" ... etc
Inside your foreach loop on every iteration, your $flight variable will hold the value of any one single column like "id", "from", "to" etc. So $flight[key] does not exist.